# Recursively nested Radicals C++

Tags: c++, recursion, math

I'm trying to write a function for the first n terms of `sqrt(1+sqrt(2+sqrt(3+...)))` in C++. The constraint is that the function must be recursive and take n (the depth of the nest) as the only parameter. I do not need to return the expression itself, just what it evaluates to. For example:

```
n=1 -> sqrt(1)                 # which evaluates to 1  
n=2 -> sqrt(1+sqrt(2))         # which evaluates to 1.55377  
n=3 -> sqrt(1+sqrt(2+sqrt(3))) # which evaluates to 1.7122
```

I've tried:

```
float nestedRadical(float n){
   if (n==1){
       return sqrt(1);
   }else{
       return sqrt(n + nestedRadical(n-1));
   }
}
```

This code causes `1` to be the most deeply nested radical, when it should be the highest. How should should I approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe try to define a helper function which goes from 1 to n instead of n to 1. The helper would need to know the original value of n, so that it can tell when to stop. So the helper would take two arguments, the current nesting depth and the highest nesting depth needed (or something like that). Then your `nestedRadical(n)` calls the helper as `nestedRadicalHelper(1, n)`, then the helper does the rest of the work.

Comment: @Metras Why is the return type of the function bool?!

Answer (score 0):

Examine and analyze nested radicals carefully. Write on paper, even if needed. then you will understand better.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

double recursivelNestedRadicals(int n, int i) {
    double res = 0;

    if(i-1 == n)
        return res;

    else
        res = sqrt(i + recursivelNestedRadicals(n, i+1));
}

int main() {
    int number;
    cout<<"Enter number: ";
    cin>>number;
    cout<<recursivelNestedRadicals(number, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand the code correctly we start at 1 and go up to the nth root. Is an approach possible where we only take one parameter for our recursive function? I imagine we would start at the nth root and then work our way backwards to sqrt(1).